# Android "Sources not found" while reading data from internal memory file

Tags: android

I am trying to read some saved data on internal memory file (todoItems_file.txt).

During debugging, while loop reads only second line of the file, then it reads null but it can't end the loop at this point. I got a lot of not found sources.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);

    lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);


    createDataFile();       

    File file = getFilesDir();
    String dir_path = file.getPath();
    String line = "";
    //----------------------------------------- read saved items from data file
    try {
        FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream(dir_path + "/" + file_name); 
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(isr); 

        while(br.readLine() != "null"){
            line = br.readLine();
            items.add(line);

        }
        br.close();
        isr.close();
        fis.close();
        //String vv = 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void createDataFile(){
    try {

        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(file_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE | Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

        osw.append("first" + "\r\n");
        osw.append("sec" + "\r\n");

        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got these new tap open when debugging choreographer.class  class file editor  source not found

Answer (score 0):

This seems wrong:

```
while(br.readLine() != "null")
```

Try without quotes instead:

```
while(br.readLine() != null)
```

Comment: But:: it still reads only the second line of the file  and source not found

Comment: can you post the exact error message and stack trace you get?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue :** You are reading two lines in every iteration, since `readLine()` is called twice per iteration.

```
    while(br.readLine() != "null"){ // 1st invocation
        line = br.readLine(); // 2nd invocation
        items.add(line);
    }
```

**Solution:** You should call `readLine()` only once per iteration and store it's return value in a string variable as shown below:

```
   String line;  
  // read every line, one at a time from the file into the line variable   
  while((line = br.readLine()) != null){  
     items.add(line)      
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while(br.readLine() != "null"){
    line = br.readLine();
    items.add(line);
}
```

with:

```
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    items.add(line); 
}
```